# I have error related retrofit dependency how can I resolve it?

Tags: java, android, dependencies, retrofit, retrofit2

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0.
I have this kind of error and how it to solve.
I have already added dependency like
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies
Retrofit Libraries
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
OkHttp Libraries
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'

Answer (score 0):

Change the version like:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
```

for the gson:

```
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```

Then it will work.